# Joining List of item

Tags: c#, linq

I want to achieve the below format data from to different List.

[image: Data I want to achieve]

Using the below code:

```
List<SalesOrder> SalesOrder = new List<SalesOrder>();
List<Sales> Sales = new List<Sales>();

SalesOrder.Add(new SalesOrder { VoucherNumber = "1", Date = "01-04-2018", LedgerName = "Sales Party", Refernce = "1", StockItem = "Item 1", Description = "", qnt = "1200", Rate = "120", Amount = "14000" });
SalesOrder.Add(new SalesOrder { VoucherNumber = "1", Date = "01-04-2018", LedgerName = "Sales Party", Refernce = "1", StockItem = "Item 2", Description = "", qnt = "78", Rate = "980", Amount = "76440" });
SalesOrder.Add(new SalesOrder { VoucherNumber = "2", Date = "04-04-2018", LedgerName = "Sales Party", Refernce = "2", StockItem = "Item 3", Description = "", qnt = "350", Rate = "345", Amount = "120750" });

Sales.Add(new Sales { VoucherNumber = "1", Date = "05-04-2018", Refernce = "1", LedgerName = "SalePartyLedgerName", Description = "", qnt = "100 nos", Rate = "120", Amount = "12000" });
Sales.Add(new Sales { VoucherNumber = "1", Date = "05-04-2018", Refernce = "1", LedgerName = "SalePartyLedgerName", Description = "", qnt = "40 nos", Rate = "980", Amount = "39200" });



var res = from so in SalesOrder
          join s in Sales
          on so.VoucherNumber equals s.Refernce into ps
          from s in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new
          {
              SONO = so.VoucherNumber,
              SODate = so.Date,
              SoCustomer = so.LedgerName,
              SoItem = so.StockItem,
              SoDescription = so.Description,
              SoUnit = so.qnt,
              SoRate = so.Rate,
              SoAmount = so.Amount,

              SInvNum = s?.VoucherNumber ?? string.Empty,
              SDate = s?.Date ?? string.Empty,
              SQnt = s?.qnt ?? string.Empty,
              SRate = s?.Rate ?? string.Empty,
              SAmount = s?.Amount ?? string.Empty                 
          };
```

I am getting the following result:
[image: Result of the above code]

I want to merge those two List's based on a ref number. Currently what i have tried is based on left join but the item is getting repeated by number of item present in the 2nd list. You may note that 1st image show only 2 line of data containing "1" as a number and my c# code is creating 4 of them and data is also getting repeated and spitted in next line too.

What changes i need to do for getting the result what i want?

Any help with an example will be greatly appreciated.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Have a look at `GroupBy`

Comment: Make the new item either a Class or a DataTable where you can specify the type.  You are using anonymous object for destination which will keep same format as source.  Or you could specify format in current code use .ToString(format).  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8